# Installation of mod_headers.c not successful

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Apache/2.4.18 server in Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.0. I wanted to add in /etc/apache2./apache2.conf the following:

```
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
```

I have read that i must install `mod_headers.c`and to do the commands are:

```
a2enmod headers
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Although when i do `apache2 -l`

```
Compiled in modules:

  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

so `mod_headers.c` still does not exist.. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a2enmod` will activate a dynamically loaded module. `apache2 -l` lists only modules statically compiled into the apache2 binary.

`man apache2` reveals:

```
   -l     Output  a  list  of  modules compiled into the server. 
          This will not list dynamically loaded modules
          included using the LoadModule directive.
```

You can list all modules with this:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

If the module is loaded, the output should include this line:

```
headers_module (shared)
```